# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number - Can't find the duplicate

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

when I tried to run this extract part of a function in SQL (PHP/PDO) I get the following error:

Error submitting query to databse: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :membernobooking2

The function passes these variables:

```
function makeBooking($memberNo2,$car,$bayID,$bookingDate,$bookingHour,$duration) {}
```

And the specific part of the code is:

```
$stmt4 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO booking (bookingid, bayid, bookingdate, bookinghour, duration, memberno, car) 
                VAlUES (DEFAULT, :bayIDBooking, :bookingDateBooking, :bookingHourBooking, :durationBooking, 
                    (SELECT memberNo FROM PeerPark.Member m WHERE (m.email = ':membernobooking') OR (m.nickname = ':membernobooking')), :carBooking) 
                RETURNING bookingid  ");
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':bayIDBooking',$bayID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':bookingDateBooking',$bookingDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':bookingHourBooking',$bookingHour,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':durationBooking',$duration,PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':membernobooking',$memberNo2,PDO::PARAM_STR):
                    $stmt4->bindValue(':carBooking',$car,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt4->execute();
```

I saw that there is a very similar question asked but I do not believe I am getting any duplicates. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: remove the quotes `'` from around your binds in your values `(m.email = ':membernobooking') OR (m.nickname = ':membernobooking')`

Comment: Wow super rookie mistake there. Thanks so much Fred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes `'` from around your binds in your values.

```
(m.email = ':membernobooking') OR (m.nickname = ':membernobooking')
           ^                ^                   ^                ^
```

to

```
(m.email = :membernobooking) OR (m.nickname = :membernobooking)
```

Placeholders should not contain quotes.

**Reference(s):**

- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements